# dynamic drop down menu with values returned in JSON format in Java

Tags: java, json, swing, http

I am developing an application which sets up an http connection with a website and by using GET call. I am getting Data Set IDs and I want to show these DATA SET ID's in a drop down menu, so that the user can select it.

I also want to store the selected data set id in a variable as it will be used in future in my application.

This is how I am getting the values in DSid (string array to store data set id returned in JSON format )

```
URL urlDS = new URL("http:/link.json?key="+APIkey);
HttpURLConnection httpConDS = (HttpURLConnection) urlDS.openConnection(); 
StringBuilder sbDS = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLineDS = inDS.readLine()) != null) {
    sbDS.append(inputLineDS);
    System.out.println(inputLineDS);
}
String ResultDS;
ResultDS=sbDS.toString();
System.out.println("result:"+ResultDS);
String jsonSourceDS = ResultDS;
JSONArray arrayDS;
try {
    arrayDS = new JSONArray(jsonSourceDS);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayDS.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject firstObject = (JSONObject) arrayDS.get(i);
        System.out.println("Data set ID  " + firstObject.getString("datasetId"));

        DSid[i]=firstObject.getString("datasetId");
        ++countDSid;
    }
}
```

I used `JComboBox` but it is not helping me.

```
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String selected = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        labelp3.setText("You selected: " + selected);
    }
} );
```

and this in the constructor of my Log-in class

```
 JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(DSid);
```

This DSid is an string array which  is storing the data set id, using GET call.

I am not able to create the drop down menu with the data set ids, it is being empty if I am using these.

So how can I create dynamic drop down menu and also store the selected value in a variable?

The values shown in data set (2,3) are given by me statically in the DSid array in the class login.